# Parse CSV file containing a Unicode character using OpenCSV

Tags: java, netbeans, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to parse a .csv file with [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in NetBeans 6.0.1. My file contains some Unicode character. When I write it in output the character appears in other form, like (HJ1'-E/;). When when I open this file in Notepad, it looks ok.

The code that I used:

```
CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(new FileReader("d:\\a.csv"),',','\'',1);
    String[] line;
    while((line=reader.readNext())!=null){
        StringBuilder stb=new StringBuilder(400);
        for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
            stb.append(line[i]);
            stb.append(";");
        }
        System.out.println( stb);
    }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First you need to know what encoding your file is in, such as UTF-8 or UTF-16. What's generating this file to start with?

After that, it's relatively straightforward - you need to create a `FileInputStream` wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` instead of just a `FileReader`. (`FileReader` always uses the default encoding for the system.) Specify the encoding to use when you create the `InputStreamReader`, and if you've picked the right one, everything should start working.

Note that you don't need to use OpenCSV to check this - you could just read the text of the file yourself and print it all out. I'm not sure I'd trust `System.out` to be able to handle non-ASCII characters though - you may want to find a different way of examining strings, such as printing out the individual values of characters as integers (preferably in hex) and then comparing them with the [charts at unicode.org](http://unicode.org/charts). On the other hand, you could try the right encoding and see what happens to start with...

EDIT: Okay, so if you're using UTF-8:

```
CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("d:\\a.csv"), "UTF-8"), 
    ',', '\'', 1);
String[] line;
while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder(400);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
         stb.append(line[i]);
         stb.append(";");
    }
    System.out.println(stb);
}
```

(I hope you have a try/finally block to close the file in your real code.)

Comment: Im getting `The constructor CSVReader(InputStreamReader, char) is undefined` with this solution

Comment: @Code_Mode: My code doesn't try to call such a constructor - it tries to call `CSVReader(InputStreamReader, char, char, int)`. Does *that* work for you?

Comment: Even for this , getting same error. I am using OpenCSV4.1 and its constructor does not have this constructor

Comment: @Code_Mode: Looking at the documentation and the [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVReader.java#l145), it should be there, but deprecated. Consider using CSVReaderBuilder instead.