# Unicode aware CSV parser in Java

Tags: java, unicode, csv, utf-8, cjk

I'm looking for Java implementation of CSV (comma separated values) parser with proper handling of Unicode data, e.g. UTF-8 CSV files with Chinese text. I suppose such a parser should internally use code point related methods while iterating, comparing etc. 
Apache 2 license or similar would work the best.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/ try it

Comment: Most CSV parsers should handle 16-bit characters.  Are you saying you need 32-bit character support?

Comment: I tried couple of parsers, including one in-house from other project.
So it seems they all do attempt internally to split fields by iterating using 1) read line 2) go over line using charAt() and append to some temp char. I have UTF-8 files with Chinese text, some symbols are encoded with 3 bytes, so that doesn't work. It seems even starting BOM is not handled correctly in many parsers.

Comment: "Proper handling" of UTF-8 should not be an issue if it's a real UTF-8, because it's already handled by Java (InputStreamReader with explicit charset), not something that Parser should care about.
The question is quite old, maybe it's high time to accept some answer?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe in reinventing the wheel. So I do not want to write my own parser and go through the same headaches someone else did.

I personally like the CSV Parser from [Ostermiller](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html). They also have a Maven Repository if interested.

---

You can also check out [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). There is a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695699/parse-csv-files-that-contain-unicode-character-using-opencsv) already about parsing unicode.

Comment: This one looks good and even it is stated directly to support Chinese, but its GPL I think, that is something I cannot use for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/)?

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty easy to write yourself. Open the file with a FileInputStream and an InputStreamReader that uses UTF-8. Wrap it in a BufferedReader you can iterate through it using readLine(). Get each line as a String. Use regular expressions to split it into fields.

The only tricky part is constructing the regexes so they don't treat commas that are enclosed within quotes as field delimiters.

The approach above is a bit inefficient, but fast enough for most apps. If you have real performance requirements then you'll need something that iterates through characters. I wrote one a few years ago that uses a state machine that worked ok.

Comment: That's more straightforward than I can afford without having bad dreams at night :-) I'm now looking for ready-to-be-used library.

Comment: this is actually *not* straightforward.  The simple case can be handled with regexes, but when you get into fields that themselves contain commas or the (optional) quote delimeters, Regex will not work.  Regex is a fine tool for certain jobs, but it is not a substitute for a well written parser.

Comment: I think it will work, just will be a bit more complex. Google gives  good regexp to use instantly, see here for example: http://www.programmersheaven.com/user/Jonathan/blog/73-Splitting-CSV-with-regex/