# Reading file with bad encoding. CP1252 vs UTF-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, nio

I have byte array, which put in InputStreamReader and do some manipulations with it.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr));
```

JVM has default cp1252 encoding, but file, which I translating to byte array has utf-8 encoding. Also this file has german umlauts. And when I put byte array in InputStreamReader, java decode umlauts to wrong symbols. For example ü represent as Ã¼. I'm tried to put "UTF-8" and Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()); to InputStreamReader constructor, translate strings from reader to string with new encoding via new String(oldStr.getBytes("cp1252"), "UTF-8); but it's not helped. In debugger in reader variable I see StreamDecoder parameter, which has "decoder" with MS1252$Decoder value. Maybe It's solving of my problem, but I not understand, how I can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)` constructor and set charset by yourself.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: It seems you read or manipulate data in a wrong way. By the way cp1252 supports german language. Can you show code that read file and output result?

Comment: Maybe try to set default JVM encoding like this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: Maybe OpenCSV damage the file. When I'm get Reader I put it in OpenCSV parse method. For example file with only one word - Zurückziehung, but on output I have ZurÃ¼ckziehung

Comment: with ANSI encoding I have no trouble, but I need to work with UTF-8.

Comment: I think here is a solution of your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695699/parse-csv-files-that-contain-unicode-character-using-opencsv

Comment: It's not solution, I do same manipulations: I'm creating InputStreamReader with "UTF-8" encoding and put this in CSVReader.

Comment: So maybe your .txt file is not in UTF-8 encoding? I can't find any other explanation.

Comment: Look like your file is in cp1252 and you try to read and manipulate it in UTF-8

Comment: Notepad++ say, that it's UTF-8 file :)

Comment: Lets take a look on bytes: 
ö -> C3B6 in UTF8. 
In windows-1252 C3 ->Ã B6 ->¶ 

so ö ->Ã¶

So you should find in your code where you still use cp1252 and damage data. Go with debugger and check data on each step and find where it happen

Comment: It was environment problem. I solve my problem with Charset. But thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error and finally solved the issue by adding this to the JVM startup options :

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```