# Java Replace Alt Codes

Tags: java

I have a csv file that is alt code delimited.  "Alt 26" or → sign.

```
this.delimiter = '→';
CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(inputStreamReader, this.delimiter);
for (int i = 0; i < reader.getHeaderCount(); i++) {
    //header fields is no being seperated as per delimiter specified.
}
```

Code above won't work as the header/fields are not being seperated.  Any idea how to replace them?

Comment: Are you *sure* that your CSV file actually contains → characters to separate the fields, or are you using a text editor that uses → to display tab characters?

Comment: When I open in notepad it shows tab but opening it in excel it shows the arrow sign (alt 26).   Using it in excel (alt26) will separate the fields correctly

Comment: That means that the file really contains tab characters, not arrows. Excel just translates tabs to arrow characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file with UTF-8 encoding:

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("d:\\a.csv"), "UTF-8"),
```

like in this question:
[Parse CSV file containing a Unicode character using OpenCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695699/parse-csv-file-containing-a-unicode-character-using-opencsv)